# central admin page does not open properly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, central-administration

After installing SharePoint 2013. I had open the central admin page, But it does not have any image and CSS style.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6738671e-dfc7-4446-9151-b111ec14ec00/just-upgraded-a-farm-now-sharepoint-css-is-not-loading-and-javascript-function-undefined?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 2):

Are there any error messages when you installed SP?

Try to run configuration wizard again.

Check if the Windows Authentication is enable (in IIS > sites > CA). If not, enable and rest iis.

Several similar post with solutions for your reference:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3353ad18-4390-4576-90bd-7b91e4e1f577/central-administration-blank-page-after-successful-installation?forum=sharepointadmin
https://hpatel.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/getting-blank-for-sharepoint-central-administration-after-installing-sharepoint-2010-in-windows-7-64-bit/